# How to extract notes and chords from audio?

Tags: sound, signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

I have a 3-second recording of a guitar chord which [you can safely download here](http://we.tl/d4HuhB7HLP). I'm trying to use Mathematica's wavelet features to find out the notes in the chord, at least the docs says that something like this is possible.

So I import it and create a ContinuousWaveletTransform object:

```
s = Import["chord.aiff"];
cwd = ContinuousWaveletTransform[snd, GaborWavelet[6], {Automatic, 12}]
```

But I'm stuck here (there are so many wavelet functions I don't know which to use). How can I detect the frequencies for the 4 or 5 notes that make up this chords. I'd like the output to be "c", "d#", etc... and the octave for each note as well.

Reference: [frequencies of musical notes](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html)

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that, I'll try a different upload site, what would you recomend?

Comment: @Nasser I googled "upload file link" and speedy share came up first, it's not a virus, I was able to download it, but I'm adding a new upload on a different site.

Comment: @nasser Is there a way to upload the entire notebook or a zip to stackexhange?

Comment: @nasser added a new like, wetransfer is a nice site.

Comment: I got the spectrum for this, But used fft. Why do you have to use WaveletTransform for this? Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Plygo.png)

Comment: fyi, to use Wavelet, something like : `cwt = ContinuousWaveletTransform[sound, GaborWavelet[6], 
   Padding -> 0.0, SampleRate -> 44100, WaveletScale -> Automatic];` where the SampleRate is obtained from the file. As well as the Sound (imported, using Elements). I just do not know enough about Wavelets to answer your question on sound.  Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ez00h.png)

Comment: @Nasser Nice! With or without wavelets is fine by me, but how do you recover the actual notes C4 F5 etc...? I play piano so the actual note values are important to me.

Comment: Extracting notes from an audio waveform is much like extracting text from a speech waveform -- it is possible in some situations, but the algorithms are complex and finicky. There is commercial software that is reasonably good such as melodyne but even that is no panacea. http://www.celemony.com/en/melodyne/what-is-melodyne

Comment: The next time you have to upload an audio file, consider using SoundCloud.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a rather quick attempt. Define a function which converts frequencies to the nearest pitch.

```
NoteName[freq_] := Module[{notelist,freqlist,list},
  notelist = {"B"}~Join~
    Nest[Join[{"C", "C\[Sharp]/D\[Flat]", "D", "D\[Sharp]/E\[Flat]",
       "E", "F", "F\[Sharp]/G\[Flat]", "G", "G\[Sharp]/A\[Flat]", 
      "A", "A\[Sharp]/B\[Flat]", "B"}, #] &, {"C", 
    "C\[Sharp]/D\[Flat]", "D", "D\[Sharp]/E\[Flat]", "E", "F", 
    "F\[Sharp]/G\[Flat]", "G", "G\[Sharp]/A\[Flat]", "A", 
    "A\[Sharp]/B\[Flat]", "B"}, 3]~Join~{"C", "C\[Sharp]/D\[Flat]"};

  freqlist = {440.*2^(-2 - 9/12 + #/12 - 1/24),
              440.*2^(-2 - 9/12 + #/12 + 1/24)} & /@ Range[-1, 49];

  list = Transpose[{notelist,freqlist}];

  If[freq < 440.*2^(-2 - 9/12 - 1/12 - 1/24), "Too Low",
     If[freq > 440.*2^(-2 - 9/12 + 49/12 + 1/24),"Too High",
      Select[list, #[[2, 1]] < freq < #[[2, 2]] &][[1, 1]]
  ]]
]
```

Now import the data and perform the wavelet transform.

```
data = Import["chord.mp3","Data"]//First;
sampleRate = Import["chord.mp3","SampleRate"];
cwt = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data,
        GaborWavelet[6], Padding->0.0,
        SampleRate->sampleRate,
        WaveletScale->Automatic];
```

Convert the results to frequencies and pitches.

```
notes =
 (* convert scales to frequencies *)
 (#1[[1]] -> sampleRate/#1[[2]] &) /@ cwt["Scales"] //
 (* remove frequencies which are too low or too high *)
 # /. {({u_,v_} -> n_?(# < 440.*2^(-2 - 5/12 - 1/24) || # > 
          440.*2^(-2 + 40/12 + 1/24) &)) :> Sequence[]} & //
 (* Label frequencies with pitches *)
  # /. ({a_, b_} -> c_) :> ({a, b} -> {NoteName[c], c}) &
```

The result

```
{{6, 2} -> {"B", 1006.68}, {6, 3} -> {"G\[Sharp]/A\[Flat]", 846.515},
 {6, 4} -> {"F", 711.832}, {7, 1} -> {"D", 598.577},
 {7, 2} -> {"B", 503.341}, {7, 3} -> {"G\[Sharp]/A\[Flat]", 423.258},
 {7, 4} -> {"F", 355.916}, {8, 1} -> {"D", 299.288},
 {8, 2} -> {"B", 251.67},  {8, 3} -> {"G\[Sharp]/A\[Flat]", 211.629},
 {8, 4} -> {"F", 177.958}, {9, 1} -> {"D", 149.644},
 {9, 2} -> {"B", 125.835}, {9, 3} -> {"G\[Sharp]/A\[Flat]", 105.814},
 {9, 4} -> {"F", 88.979}}
```

Looks like an Fdim chord.

Comment: Thanks Timothy, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @TimothyWofford Issue: It appears that no matter which audio file I use to test your code cwt["Scales"] always returns the same essential values thus the frequency calculations always return the same values, resulting in~~> 'Fdim' each time. Could you address this?

Comment: @Steve, I said it was a quick attempt...I just looked at the documentation examples and pieced it together without testing. I assumed someone (like the OP) would verify whether it works or not. I was uncertain about the answer because every time the topic of wavelet scale vs frequency comes up, people suddenly become vague. I will do some research this weekend. Thanks for the quality control.

Comment: @M.R. Did you get Timothy's code to work for different audio files?  See my comment above.

Comment: @TimothyWofford What did you figure out this weekend?

Comment: @M.R. Did you get Timothy's code to work for different audio files? See my comment above.